# android if statement force close

Tags: android, if-statement, media-player

So i have the following code. When no sound is playing in my app and the following is called the application crashes. From my knowledge it should skip the if statement if there is no sound playing...So why is it crashing?

```
public void IfSoundPlayingThenStop()
if (currentSound.isPlaying())
    {
        currentSound.release();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that `currentSound` is not null. Also, add a logcat log.

Comment: how would i say not null? its not showing in the intellisense

Comment: Many ways to do that. You can add an if statement before: `if (currentSound == null) { Log.d("MYAPP", "currentSound is null"}`

Comment: Post the exception stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible solution, if you just don't care about the occasional null and would prefer to ignore them:

```
if (currentSound != null && currentSound.isPlaying())
    currentSound.release();
```

Otherwise, do a separate `if(currentSound == null)` check before making any other use of the variable, and handle things as necessary.